# Can I preserve Dictionary<string, string> key casing when storing in Bot Framework ConversationData?

Tags: c#, serialization, botframework

I have a use case where I want to store a `List<string, string>` in the Bot Framework's `context.ConversationData` (using an Azure Table storage as the backend, via the `TableBotDataStore` class). However, when I do so, upon retrieving the stored List, the casing of the keys has changed.

For example, I store a list like this:

```
IDictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("MyKey", "N");
context.ConversationData.SetValue("MyDictionary", dict);
```

I then try to retrieve this data in a later dialog:

```
IDictionary<string, string> dict;
context.ConversationData.TryGetValue("MyDictionary", out dict)
var found = dict.ContainsKey("MyKey");
```

However, in this example, `found` is set to `false`, as `dict` actually contains the key/value pair `{"myKey", "N"}` after deserialization. I can work around this by simply lowercasing my keys beforehand, but is there any way I can configure the serialization/deserialization of `ConversationData` to preserve casing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by changing the way that my JSON formatter was configured. I updated the `Register` method in my `WebApiConfig.cs`, as follows:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Json settings
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver { NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy { ProcessDictionaryKeys = false } };
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver { NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy { ProcessDictionaryKeys = false } },
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    };

//...
}
```

Now, the `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` will preserve the casing of Dictionary keys when storing and retrieving a user's ConversationData from the Azure Table storage.